# getting postgresql to run on port 5432 under OS X 10.6 after machine failure

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, osx-snow-leopard

I am getting theses errors upon starting ALL (well 4 of 4 tested) rails3 applications under OS X 10.6.8

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::Error)
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

or

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

followed  by the same request for port 5432.

Locally I have 9.1.3, 9.2.4 and 9.3.4 installed.  9.3.4 update was installed because of an attempt to install postGIS.

```
brew info postgresql
postgresql: stable 9.3.4, devel 9.4beta1
http://www.postgresql.org/
Conflicts with: postgres-xc
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.3 (2746 files, 36M)
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4 (2831 files, 39M)
  Built from source
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.4 (2921 files, 40M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/postgresql.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl ✔, readline ✔
Recommended: ossp-uuid ✔
```

The first error is for an application with a `gem 'pg', '0.15.1'`, while the second is set at `0.17.1`.  This is a consequence of having updated via homebrew.  The first does not have the proper compilation to the new 9.3.4 version, recompiling with 0.17.1 generates the second ConnectionBad error.

my /tmp/ directory has an `.s.PGSQL.5433` and sister lock file, indicating it wants to run on port 5433.

Upgraded applications were running previously.  *The machine has had some power failures since then*.

```
ps auxw | grep post
postgres   287   0.0  0.1  2465608   5204   ??  SNs  11:14AM   0:00.31 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdworker MDSImporterWorker com.apple.Spotlight.ImporterWorker.502
postgres   141   0.0  0.0  2446204    388   ??  Ss   11:13AM   0:00.36 postgres: stats collector process
postgres   139   0.0  0.0  2473664   1700   ??  Ss   11:13AM   0:00.41 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
postgres   137   0.0  0.0  2473532    556   ??  Ss   11:13AM   0:01.58 postgres: wal writer process
postgres   135   0.0  0.0  2473532    736   ??  Ss   11:13AM   0:02.13 postgres: writer process
postgres   130   0.0  0.0  2446204    328   ??  Ss   11:13AM   0:00.46 postgres: logger process
postgres    58   0.0  0.2  2473532   6696   ??  Ss   11:12AM   0:00.44 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/postmaster -D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data
jerdvo    5966   0.0  0.0  2435120    536 s001  S+    5:32PM   0:00.00 grep post
```

so there is a process running postgre, based on the original 9.1 version.  I believe this is because I had the (unenlightened?) idea to install pgAdmin3 which resides in that directory.

Now I feel there are too many rabbits to run after.  As best I understand,  system PATH ought to bet set so that the psql and its libpq are aligned.

**My main goal is to get access to all the applications via the console, thus getting PG to run on 5432.**

Is unninstalling pgadmin3 a good idea? If so, what is best route?

Finally, I also have another objective in installing PostGIS.  Would installing [the postgre app](http://postgresapp.com/) further gum up the issue?

*update*

```
ps auxww | grep ^postgres
postgres   182   0.0  0.0  2446204    240   ??  Ss    9:19PM   0:00.61 postgres: stats collector process
postgres   181   0.0  0.0  2473664   1332   ??  Ss    9:19PM   0:00.67 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
postgres   180   0.0  0.0  2473532    280   ??  Ss    9:19PM   0:02.69 postgres: wal writer process
postgres   179   0.0  0.0  2473532    484   ??  Ss    9:19PM   0:03.63 postgres: writer process
postgres   177   0.0  0.0  2446204    248   ??  Ss    9:19PM   0:00.77 postgres: logger process
postgres    57   0.0  0.1  2473532   5356   ??  Ss    9:19PM   0:00.46 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/postmaster -D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data
postgres  2802   0.0  0.1  2465608   5004   ??  SNs  10:58AM   0:00.13 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdworker MDSImporterWorker com.apple.Spotlight.ImporterWorker.502
```

**Update and resolution**
For those who stumble upon these conditions...

Thanks to Craig and his pointers.  Under the assumption that *machine failure* and *conflicts with versions* (OS X version, the homebrew versions, the pgadmin3 app...) I decided to wipe clean.  [Back-up(s) required].  pgadmin has its own uninstaller which, sitting in /Library/ directory, hopefully also took care of OS X's mess.  then

```
brew remove postgresql
```

and, for previous versions,    brew remove --force postgresql

```
brew install postgresql
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l logfile start
```

and need to

```
initdb
```

before reloading data from back-ups.

Comment: Are you sure PG is listening on localhost:5432?  The existence of that tmp file is for unix-domain sockets.  It has nothing to do with TCP sockets.  Ignore Rails for the moment and make sure you can connect with psql itself.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-connection.html

Comment: I am certain it is not listening... `ls -A /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
ls: /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432: No such file or directory`   but there is a /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5433 socket opened.

Comment: Having let others (Apple, application installer) do the configuring, I am totally extraneous to using the documentation.  How would I go about changing that port to 5432?

Answer (score 2):

Change the `port` directive in `postgresql.conf` to `5432`.

You might need to stop some existing other PostgreSQL install if there's another one busy on 5432 already.

Comment: Oddity. The port in postgresql.conf is set at 5432.  But a socket file (in tmp directory) was created for port 5433, while there is no 5432 socket file. On a production server, the postgresql.conf file is actually configured `#port = 5432`.  Apple has this etc/services configuration file where 5432 is allocated to postgresql.  One assumption is that it launches the other postgreSQL process, since it sees 5432 is usually allocated, OS X bumps it to 5433?   But then which is which?

Comment: You have an init script / launchd config / etc that's overriding it with the PGPORT environment var or supplying the port config option on the pg_ctl / postgres command line.

Comment: trying to dig along those lines; not finding anything to date.  However `launchctl list` is showing homebrew without a pid so it seems homebrew is not launching.  The other two launchAgents of my active user have a pid (and one just ran in the background). So it looks like homebrew is in limbo somewhere, probably due to a power issue that crashed this machine...

Comment: What is the command line of the main postgres or  pg_ctl process as listed in `ps`? The one with a -D argument.